# Disqus Kirby CMS local development

Tags: php, content-management-system, disqus, kirby

I'm developing a Kirby site locally. I'm Trying to add Disqus comments to my article pages. I am following this [EXPLANATION OF HOW TO DO SO](http://getkirby.com/docs/solutions/blog/comments)

I have followed it word for word. I have downloaded the following snippet and added it to my snippets folder:

```
1:<?php
2:
3:// set the defaults
4:if(!isset($disqus_shortname))  die('ThisIsMyShortname');
5:if(!isset($disqus_title))      $disqus_title = $page->title();
6:if(!isset($disqus_developer))  $disqus_developer = false;
7:if(!isset($disqus_identifier)) $disqus_identifier = $page->uri();
8:if(!isset($disqus_url))        $disqus_url = thisURL();
9:
10:$disqus_title     = addcslashes($disqus_title, "'");
11:$disqus_developer = ($disqus_developer) ? 'true' : 'false';
12:
13:?>
14:<div id="disqus_thread"></div>
15:<script type="text/javascript">
16:var disqus_shortname  = '<?php echo $ThisIsMyShortname ?>'; // required: replace example with   your forum shortname
17:var disqus_title      = '<?php echo html($disqus_title) ?>';
18:var disqus_developer  = '<?php echo $disqus_developer ?>'; // developer mode
19:var disqus_identifier = '<?php echo $disqus_identifier ?>';
20:var disqus_url        = '<?php echo $disqus_url ?>';
21:
22:(function() {
23:var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
24:dsq.src = 'http://' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
25:(document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
26:})();
27:</script>
28:<noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the <a href="http://disqus.com/?ref_noscript">comments powered by Disqus.</a></noscript>
29:<a href="http://disqus.com" class="dsq-brlink">blog comments powered by <span class="logo-disqus">Disqus</span></a>
```

On lines 4 and 16 I have changed the shortname to my ThisIsMyShortname (my actual short name)

Then to place the comments on my page I have:

```
<?php snippet('disqus', array('disqus_shortname' => 'WeShapeDigital', 'disqus_developer' => true )) ?>
```

I have included

```
'disqus_developer' => true ))
```

because I am working locally and this should apparently allow Disqus to at least not error.

The error being shown is:

[image: Error message]

Any help would be great!

Comment: thats strange.. `thisURL()` still works for me in the current version. Do you have the current version 2.0.3? But afaik it is deprecated. `$page->url()` is the new `thisURL()`. Try this. And please show us the full error, not just the snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem I found out that I didnt need to enter my short name within the snippet. If you are using kirby1 you don't need to change it at all. If you are using Kirby2 on line 8 of the snippet you do need to change

```
thisURL()
```

to

```
url::current()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just get the latest version. `thisUrl()` has been [readded in Kirby 2.0.3](https://github.com/getkirby/kirby/commit/85b51716f43b95e9db7aa0662e4ecb2c83685af1).